# Hyper-V VM doesn't get IP on start

Tags: windows, networking, hyper-v, dhcp

When I start a VM it doesn't get an IP  from DHCP.

It has a timeout so I need to:

ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew

multiple times

I do this with startup application on Windows Server 2019

```
while ($true) {
    IF (((Test-NetConnection www.google.com -Port 80 -InformationLevel "Detailed").TcpTestSucceeded) -eq $true){
        break;
    }ELSE{
        ipconfig /release
        ipconfig /renew
    }
    start-sleep -seconds 1
}
```

Switch is external

How to fix this to get an IP at startup?

Comment: Do you have portfast, or it's equivalent, enabled on your physical switches?

Comment: @joeqwerty no i don't

Comment: Does your DHCP get requests from that client, or is it just sending NACKs?

Comment: seending NACKS only but sometime it sucssess